# Two asp.net mvc 3 application on one server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Can I have one mvc application under http://www.servername.com and another under http://www.servername.com/SecondApp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You just need to configure the SecondApp directory as its own "application" in IIS.

See: [Creating an IIS application](http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/appstartpoint.asp).